# How to group Date and time data from API

Tags: ruby, date, parsing, ruby-hash

I am trying to group data I am getting from an API to serve to our front application. I mean group "time" by "date".
dates: `{date1: [time1, time2, timeN], date2: [time1...]}`

My input is like this:

```
{"date"=>"2017-04-04T00:00:00", "time"=>"1754-01-01T13:00:00"}
{"date"=>"2017-04-04T00:00:00", "time"=>"1754-01-01T14:00:00"}
{"date"=>"2017-04-05T00:00:00", "time"=>"1754-01-01T12:00:00"}
{"date"=>"2017-04-05T00:00:00", "time"=>"1754-01-01T13:00:00"}
```

And my output should be like this:

```
dates: [{date: "2017-04-04T00:00:00", availableTimes: ["1754-01-01T13:00:00", "1754-01-01T14:00:00"]}, {date: "2017-04-05T00:00:00", availableTimes: ["1754-01-01T12:00:00", "1754-01-01T13:00:00"]}]
```

I am trying to do this this way but without going into loop madness. I have the following:

```
dates  = Hash[input_data.map{|sd| [sd.date, [""]]}]
```

This gives me the data outpout like this:

```
{"2017-04-04T00:00:00"=>[""],
 "2017-04-05T00:00:00"=>[""],
 "2017-04-11T00:00:00"=>[""],
 "2017-04-12T00:00:00"=>[""],
 "2017-04-18T00:00:00"=>[""],
 "2017-04-19T00:00:00"=>[""],
 "2017-04-25T00:00:00"=>[""],
 "2017-04-26T00:00:00"=>[""]}
```

Comment: Just curious : what is this time format? What's `1754-01-01`?

Comment: Actually I do not know, just receive this info from API, it is dummy data at the moment so that could be why the date is like 1754 :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that output because your `map` function is not actually modifying any sort of data structure. It is simply returning a new array full of arrays that contain the date and an array with an empty string. Basically, this isn't going to be done with just a single map call.

So, the basic algorithm would be:

1. Find array of all unique dates
2. Loop through unique dates and use `select` to only get the date/time pairs for the current date in the loop iteration
3. Set up the data in the format you prefer

This code will have `filteredDates` be in the format you need the data

```
filteredDates = { dates: [] }
uniqueDates = input_data.map { |d| d["date"] }.uniq # This is an array of only unique dates
uniqueDates.each do |date|
    dateTimes = input_data.select { |d| d["date"] == date }
    newObj = { date: date }
    newObj[:availableTimes] = dateTimes.map { |d| d["time"] }
    filteredDates[:dates].push(newObj)
end
```

Here is what `filteredDates` will look like:

```
{:dates=>[{:date=>"2017-04-04T00:00:00", :availableTimes=>["1754-01-01T13:00:00", "1754-01-01T14:00:00"]}, {:date=>"2017-04-05T00:00:00", :availableTimes=>["1754-01-01T12:00:00", "1754-01-01T13:00:00"]}]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just one possible way:

```
input.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) do |h, m|
  m[h['date']] << h['time']
end.map { |k, v| { date: k, avaliable_times: v } }
#=> [{:date=>"2017-04-04T00:00:00", :avaliable_times=>["1754-01-01T13:00:00", "1754-01-01T14:00:00"]},
#    {:date=>"2017-04-05T00:00:00", :avaliable_times=>["1754-01-01T12:00:00", "1754-01-01T13:00:00"]}]
```

Actually, it seems like your data structure would be more concise without last `map`, I mean:

```
#=> {"2017-04-04T00:00:00"=>["1754-01-01T13:00:00", "1754-01-01T14:00:00"],
#    "2017-04-05T00:00:00"=>["1754-01-01T12:00:00", "1754-01-01T13:00:00"]}
```

Comment: Indeed. The second format would be much easier/faster to work with.

Answer (score 1):

There is many ways you can do this, one way is to create a new hash, and set the default value to be an array, then loop over the results and insert the dates:

```
dates = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
input_data.each{ |sd| dates[sd["date"]] << sd["time"] }
```

Comment: This returns `{"2017-04-04T00:00:00"=>["1754-01-01T13:00:00", "1754-01-01T14:00:00"], "2017-04-05T00:00:00"=>["1754-01-01T12:00:00", "1754-01-01T13:00:00"]}`, which is not the required format. Also, it should be noted that this does not return the new value of `dates`. If, for example, it were wrapped in a method, you'd need a final line `dates`.

Comment: I'd recommend getting familiar with `each_with_object`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

```
dates = [{"date"=>"2017-04-04T00:00:00", "time"=>"1754-01-01T13:00:00"},
         {"date"=>"2017-04-04T00:00:00", "time"=>"1754-01-01T14:00:00"},
         {"date"=>"2017-04-05T00:00:00", "time"=>"1754-01-01T12:00:00"},
         {"date"=>"2017-04-05T00:00:00", "time"=>"1754-01-01T13:00:00"}]

dates.group_by { |g| g["date"] }.
      map { |k,v| { date: k, available_times: v.map { |h| h["time"] } } }
  #=> [{:date=>"2017-04-04T00:00:00",
  #     :available_times=>["1754-01-01T13:00:00", "1754-01-01T14:00:00"]},
  #    {:date=>"2017-04-05T00:00:00",
  #     :available_times=>["1754-01-01T12:00:00", "1754-01-01T13:00:00"]}]
```

The first step produces the following intermediate value:

```
dates.group_by { |g| g["date"] }      
  #=> {"2017-04-04T00:00:00"=>
  #     [{"date"=>"2017-04-04T00:00:00", "time"=>"1754-01-01T13:00:00"},
  #      {"date"=>"2017-04-04T00:00:00", "time"=>"1754-01-01T14:00:00"}],
  #    "2017-04-05T00:00:00"=>
  #     [{"date"=>"2017-04-05T00:00:00", "time"=>"1754-01-01T12:00:00"},
  #      {"date"=>"2017-04-05T00:00:00", "time"=>"1754-01-01T13:00:00"}]}
```

Comment: I also thought about `group_by` but was confused by using nested `map` :).

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more elegant ways, but

```
results = Hash.new
dates.each do |date|
  d, t = date['date'].split('T') # (clean up/split date and time formatting)
  results.key?(d) ? nil : results[d] = Array.new
  results[d] << t
end
puts results
# => {"2017-04-04"=>["13:00:00", "14:00:00"], "2017-04-05"=>["12:00:00", "13:00:00"]}
```